# E-commerce CMS allow other people to sell products

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce

Do you know of an e commerce cms that would allow other people to sell products on my site and I take a certain percentage of the sale? 
Thanks!

Comment: That's  what we call middle platform aka seller platform.You can even use word-press with there e-commerce plugin

Answer (score 0):

You could try magento's multi store feature, assign each seller to a store.  Not sure how you would handle the transactions.  No other e-commerce solution comes to mind with those features.  look for a plugin with the feature's you require or build your own.  creating your own plugin for magento would be alot less time consuming than building your own geared towards what you describe/require.